# よりに meaning in this context

Tags: grammar, translation

Context:
The protagonist did some kind of magic the day before and now cannot move the left side of his body.

> 「……ふん。投影をしたと凛から聞いていたが、やはりそうか。
>   半身の感覚がなく、動作が**中よりに**七センチほどずれているのだろう？」
>
> [I heard from Tohsaka that you did Projection, but it's just as I thought.
>   You can't feel half of your body and your movement is off by 7 cm from the center, am I right?

I think it means "From the center", but the translation is:

> "……Heh. I heard you did projection, but it really is true, huh? Half your body is numb and your actions are misplaced about seven centimeters inside of you, right?"

Which would be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given translation is correct in regards to the word "より", as it means "approaching (a specific location or direction)". It comes from the word "寄る".

[from goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/228477/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A/):

> ある方向・場所などに近づいて位置すること。また、その位置。「新ビルが駅―に建つ」「北―の風」「右―の思想」

---

Now, I believe it is also possible for the sentence to mean "misplaced about 7 centimeters towards the center", where the center could be a point not necessarily within the body, but this is perhaps more evident with the full context.

Also, if we are nitpicking, I believe the "but" in your translation is a bit awkward, and not entirely faithful to the meaning of the original. The original meaning is closer to:

> I had heard [something] and wasn't sure I believed it, but it appears to be true after all!